# C++, CryptoPP decrypted data first 16 bytes are junk

Tags: c++, crypto++

I use CryptoPP library and obviously I make bunch of mistakes, because I get weird results and have not idea what I am doing.

I have a lot of data to encrypt and I divide it to chunks of `N*BLOCKSIZE` (`BLOCKSIZE` is 16 bytes in my case). Therefore all chunks are full of data (no padding needed) with an exception of maybe the last chunk. In my case padding is not desired.

As I decrypt encrypted data, only the last chunk I encrypted (and it's also the first chunk I decrypt) is okay. Other chunks have the first 16 bytes messed up. Why did that happen? I have read somwhere it happens because of incorrect initialization vector. Which seems to be correct for one chunk only and not others. Also I do not know, does CryptoPP work in such a way, where it stores IV in the first block of a chunk or not.

```
    CryptoPP::SecBlock<CryptoPP::byte> key(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>("my_superb_key"), CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::SecBlock<CryptoPP::byte> iv(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>("dkdforodosoeosod5"), CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    //

    while(i_block != n_block){
        CryptoPP::byte* chunk_encrypted = new CryptoPP::byte[sz_chunk];
        CryptoPP::ArraySink sink(chunk_encrypted, sz_chunk);

        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption enc;
        enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

        CryptoPP::ArraySource(chunk, sz_chunk, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new CryptoPP::Redirector(sink)));
    }
```

The problem I see right away is I use `StreamTransformationFilter()` which does apply padding. How do I not use padding? Need other way to encrypt data. Also I encrypt bytes of data, it's not a string of human-readable characters. Which method of encryption most suitable for this purpose? Obviously not the one I am using right now.

And for decryption I use this

```
CryptoPP::SecBlock<CryptoPP::byte> key(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>("my_superb_key"), CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::SecBlock<CryptoPP::byte> iv(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>("dkdforodosoeosod5"), CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
//

CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption dec;
dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

do {
    source = new CryptoPP::byte[sz_chunk];
    CryptoPP::ArraySink sink(source, sz_chunk);

    CryptoPP::ArraySource(dest, sz_chunk, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new CryptoPP::Redirector(sink)));
} while(/* not done yet */);
```

Comment: Every part of C/C++ has a standard that details what can or can't be done or what is left up to the compiler to implement. Every library (mature library) has a detailed API that in essence does the same thing (except there is nothing left to the implementation). You need to know how to get where you want to go before you pickup the keyboard and start pecking away. There is no such thing as programming by trail and error. Know what will succeed before you write it.

Answer (score 0):

> I use CryptoPP library and obviously I make bunch of mistakes, because I get weird results and have not idea what I am doing.

In that case you might want to get a book, course or something because you can have working code that is **not** secure. Cryptography (and security in general) is a bit weird in the sense that you can entirely miss your goal while the program is running *fine*.

> As I decrypt encrypted data, only the last chunk I encrypted (and it's also the first chunk I decrypt) is okay. Other chunks have the first 16 bytes messed up. Why did that happen? I have read somwhere it happens because of incorrect initialization vector.

Yes, that's correct.

> Also I do not know, does CryptoPP work in such a way, where it stores IV in the first block of a chunk or not.

Although CryptoPP provides some higher level constructs, it does still work on the algorithm level. The algorithm doesn't define what you do with the IV, just that it needs one. How **you** calculate or store the IV is up to you.

> I have a lot of data to encrypt and I divide it to chunks of `N*BLOCKSIZE` (`BLOCKSIZE` is 16 bytes in my case). Therefore all chunks are full of data (no padding needed) with an exception of maybe the last chunk. In my case padding is not desired.

You are working with a high level crypto API that can perform streaming. In these stream implementations the plaintext is already encrypted piece-meal, so why are you defining a "chunk size" yourself? You might need that if you did want to operate on separate "messages", but you implicitly indicate that you do **not** want to do that - as each message would require padding.

> The problem I see right away is I use `StreamTransformationFilter()` which does apply padding. How do I not use padding? Need other way to encrypt data.

To use CBC on messages (that are not always a multiple of the blocksize) you will either need padding or ciphertext stealing. Most other secure modes will actually not require padding, such as CTR mode. However, if you're OK with a single pad of the message then you just need to remove the chunking and make better use of the streaming API.

Comment: yes, CBC requires padding because of fixed block size. The thing is I already provide N*BLOCKSIZE pieces and padding is not needed. But CryptoPP pads such messages anyway with an extra 16 bytes. Can I configure CryptoPP in a way, where I myself pad the last chunk and other go without padding?

Comment: And also. I'm getting first 16 bytes of all the chunks (except for one) messed up. I am using same IV all the time (or so I think?), that I also do not understand... because same key works all the time, why then same IV somehow does not work

Comment: Feel free to try to look things like that [up in the documentation](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode). I don't know why you require such things if you can perform streaming, but I digress. Usually the state of the cipher changes, having the last part of the ciphertext as "vector" instead of the one you've supplied. This could be helpful to you.